# Multiple vuetify birthday pickers in a v-for range loop

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify has a birthday picker. However i need this birthday picker in a for loop. How do i get this to work, i just started with vue and vuetify and can not get my head a round the $refs  in combination of an index concept. And i think thats what is needed here. The script is working with errors in the $refs. The idea for the picker is first to select a year, than a month and then the day

```
    <template>
    <v-container>
    <div v-for="n in 3">
    <v-menu
        ref="menu"
        v-model="menu[n]"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        min-width="290px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-text-field
                v-model="date[n]"
                label="Birthday date"
                readonly
                v-on="on"
            ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-date-picker
            ref="picker"
            v-model="date[n]"
            :max="new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
            min="1950-01-01"
            @change="save"
        ></v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
    </div>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            date: [],
            menu: [],
        }),
        watch: {
            menu (val) {
                val && setTimeout(() => (this.$refs.picker.activePicker = 'YEAR'))
            },
        },
        methods: {
            save (date) {
                this.$refs.menu.save(date)
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need/issue with this component.  I'm searching for the answer as well so I can only make suggestions based on my experience with this issue.

I've tried your same approach here but with little success.  I'm currently  creating a separate BirthDatePicker component and trying to use the v-model example from this article [Using v-model on Nested Vue Components](https://zaengle.com/blog/using-v-model-on-nested-vue-components) to get each birth-date modeled to it's corresponding value within my 'people' array of objects.

Rough example:

```
people: [{name: '', dob: '', etc...},{name: '', dob: '', etc...}]
```